# How to tabulate rating or categorical data in R?

Tags: r, crosstab, tabular

I have data from a survey. I have data from several Likert-type questions. For example: "To what extent did the following factors contribute to your decision to enroll in a PhD program?" with 4 categories: 1: Not at all; 2: To a small extent; 3: To some extent; 4: To a great extent)

I exported the data and it currently looks like this:

```
id  Q1_Item1  Q1_Item2  Q1_Item3  Q1_Item4
 1         4         4         4         2
 2         1         2         3         4
 3         3         4         4         4
 4         3         3         3         3
 5         2         1         1         1
```

I want to tabulate the data so it looks like this

```
      Not at all  To a small extent  To some extent  To a great extent 
Item1          1                  1               2                  1
Item2          1                  1               1                  2
Item3          1                  0               2                  2
Item4          1                  1               1                  2
```

where the number now represent the counts of responses under each category. How can I do this in R?

Comment: OK, so what is your question? What have you tried? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Andrie, this is actually my first question on Stackoverflow. I was trying to figure out how to format data to post here. I now realize that I posted before it was complete, but I've now edited it. Cheers,

Comment: You've modified your data significantly, and now have some entries that are larger than the count of levels ... ? You need to examine your problem statement more thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming these have been read in as factors with those text entries as labels, then this works:

```
# If the data was read in as numeric, then this will convert to factor-class
dfrm[-1] <- lapply(dfrm[-1], factor, levels=1:4, labels=c("Not at all", 
                        "To a small extent", "To some extent", "To a great extent") )
t( sapply(dfrm[-1], table) )
        Not at all To a small extent To some extent To a great extent
factor1          2                 1              4                 3
factor2          0                 0              3                 8
factor3          0                 0              3                 9
factor4          0                 0              6                 6
factor5          0                 0              3                 8
factor6          2                 0              0                10
factor7          0                 0              2                10
```

Comment: DWin, do you know if it is possible to export the table using xtable or other package? I've tried to do it using xtable with no luck.

Comment: I'm not at computer that can run R, so I cannot test my ideas. The output of that function is a matrix, so any output that handles a matrix would work. Similarly if you had a method that worked with a data.frame, you could wrap it in `as.data.frame`.